# Minimise jquery code

Tags: jquery

I currently have this jquery code

```
$('#f1').click(function() {
$('#bg').addClass('f1');
});

$('#f2').click(function() {
$('#bg').addClass('f2');
});

$('#f3').click(function() {
$('#bg').addClass('f3');
});
```

the problem is that for what I want to do I would need to write this out numerous times so was wondering how this can be shortened

Answer (score 5):

Use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) or give those elements a common class (better if you have even more elements):

```
$('#f1, #f2, #f3').click(function() { // $('.foo').click(...)
    $('#bg').addClass(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give them a class for selector, then

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
  $('#bg').addClass(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to all of them, and then just do:

```
 $('.class').click(function() {
      $('#bg').addClass($(this).attr('id'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we do like this.

```
 for(var i=1; i<=3;i++)
 {
    $('#f' + i).click(function() {
       $('#bg').addClass('f' + i);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, here's another one if you have many of those #fx divs:

```
var prefix = "f";

$("[id^="+prefix+"]").click(function() {
    $('#bg').addClass(this.id);
});
```

Or if all your elements are inside one "container" element:

```
$("#fContainer").children().click(function() {
    $('#bg').addClass(this.id);
});
```

Comment: This would match all elements that starts with **f**. Also, way slower searching like this instead of giving them a class name or by using multiple ids.

Comment: True, but then again it depends on what exactly OP needs. If you have hundreds of element, cannot use classes, and the id is prefixed with something unique (ie not `f`), it can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to use a class (as others have said) separate your function from your click assignment.

```
var clickHandler = function(){ 
   $('#bg').addClass(this.id); 
};
$('#f1, #f2, #f3').click(clickHandler);
```